# ld warning from custom compiler: ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000

Tags: c, linux, assembly, compiler-construction, ld

When trying to actually use my custom compiler for a made up language I get the following warning from ld: "ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000" it seems that ld cant find the _start tag even though it should be written to the assembly file. Here's the compiler code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STACK_SIZE          1000  // Default loop stack size
#define STACK_GROWTH_FACTOR 0.1   // How much stack to add when its full

void compile(char *asm_filename, char *src_filename);
char *string(char *str);
char *replace_extension(char *name, char *ext);

enum stage {
    COMPILE,   // Compile only
    ASSEMBLE,  // Compile and assemble only
    LINK       // Compile, assemble and link
};

struct info_t {
    char *pname;         // Process name
    char *ifilename;     // Input source code file name
    char *ofilename;     // Output file name
    enum stage ostage;   // Final stage that generates the output file
    char *arr_size;      // Memory allocated for the executable
} info;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int verbose = 0;               // 1 enables verbosity; 0 disables
    char *arr_size = "30000";      // Default size of array of cells
    char *asm_filename;            // File name for assembly code
    char *obj_filename;            // File name for object code
    char *exe_filename = "out";    // File name for executable code
    char *command;                 // Buffer for command line strings
    size_t i;                      // Counter
    size_t len;                    // Stores string lengths

    if ((info.pname = strrchr(argv[0], '/')) == NULL) {
        info.pname = argv[0];
    } else {
        info.pname++; // Address of the basename part in argv[0]
    }
    info.ifilename = NULL;
    info.ofilename = NULL;
    info.ostage = LINK; 
    info.arr_size = arr_size;

    if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file.gear\n", info.pname);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    info.ifilename = argv[1];


    // Compiling

    // Determine name for assembly code filename
    if (info.ostage == COMPILE && info.ofilename != NULL) {
        asm_filename = string(info.ofilename);
    } else {
        asm_filename = replace_extension(info.ifilename, "s"); 
    }

    if (verbose) {
        printf("Compiling: compile(\"%s\", \"%s\")\n",
               asm_filename, info.ifilename);
    }
    compile(asm_filename, info.ifilename);

    // If compile only option was specified, exit
    if (info.ostage == COMPILE) {
        free(asm_filename);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    // Assembling 

    // Determine name for object code filename
    if (info.ostage == ASSEMBLE && info.ofilename != NULL) {
        obj_filename = string(info.ofilename);
    } else {
        obj_filename = replace_extension(info.ifilename, "o"); 
    }

    // as
    len = strlen("as -o") + strlen(asm_filename) +
          strlen(obj_filename) + 2;
    if ((command = malloc(len)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Out of memory while assembling", info.pname);
    }
    sprintf(command, "as -o %s %s", obj_filename, asm_filename);

    // Assemble the asm code into its object file
    if (verbose) {
        printf("Assembling: %s\n", command);
    }
    system(command);
    free(command);

    // Assembly code file is not required after assembling
    //unlink(asm_filename);
    free(asm_filename);

    // Link object file

    // Determine name for executable code filename
    if (info.ostage == LINK && info.ofilename != NULL) {
        exe_filename = info.ofilename;
    }

    // ld
    len = strlen("ld -o") + strlen(exe_filename) +
          strlen(obj_filename) + 2;
    if ((command = malloc(len)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Out of memory while compiling", info.pname);
    }
    sprintf(command, "ld -o %s %s", exe_filename, obj_filename);

    // Link the object code to executable code using ld
    if (verbose) {
        printf("Linking: %s\n", command);
    }
    system(command);
    free(command);

    // Object code file is not needed after linking
    unlink(obj_filename);
    free(obj_filename);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    }
char *string(char *str) {
    char *new_str;
    if ((new_str = malloc(strlen(str) + 1)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Out of memory while allocating memory for "
                        "string: %s\n", info.pname, str);
        exit(1);
    }
    strcpy(new_str, str);
    return new_str;
}

char *replace_extension(char *name, char *ext) {
    char *dot = strrchr(name, '.');
    char *new_name;
    size_t len = dot == NULL ? strlen(name) : dot - name;

    if ((new_name = malloc(len + strlen(ext) + 2)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Out of memory while changing extension of "
                        "%s to %s\n", info.pname, name, ext);
        exit(1);
    }

    strncpy(new_name, name, len);
    new_name[len] = '\0';
    strcat(new_name, ".");
    strcat(new_name, ext);
    return new_name;
}

void compile(char *asm_filename, char *src_filename) {

    FILE *src;                      // Source code file
    FILE *as;                       // Assembly code file
    size_t *stack;                  // Loop stack
    size_t top = 0;                 // Next free location in stack
    size_t stack_size = STACK_SIZE; // Stack size
    size_t loop = 0;                // Used to generate loop labels
    int c;

    // Open source file
    if ((src = fopen(src_filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s: Could not read file\n",
                info.pname, src_filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Open assembly file
    if ((as = fopen(asm_filename, "w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s: Could not write file\n",
                info.pname, asm_filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Create loop stack
    if ((stack = malloc(stack_size * sizeof *stack)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Out of memory while creating loop stack "
                        "of size %lu\n", info.pname, stack_size);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Write assembly code */
    fputs(".section .bss\n", as);
    fprintf(as, "\t.lcomm buffer %s\n", info.arr_size);
    fputs(".section .text\n", as);
    fputs(".globl _start\n", as);

    while ((c = fgetc(src)) != EOF) {
        char keyword[6];
        if (fscanf(src, "%5s", keyword) == 1) {
            if (strcmp(keyword, "_START") == 0) {
                fputs("_start:\n", as);
                fputs("\tmov $buffer, %edi\n", as);
            } else if (strcmp(keyword, "_END") == 0) {
                fputs("movl $1, %eax\n", as);
                fputs("movl $0, %ebx\n", as);
                fputs("int $0x80\n", as);
            }
        }
    } 
    fclose(as);
    fclose(src);
}
```

And here's the file im attempting to run:

```
_START

_END
```

I tried using a different linker (gcc) and I expected that the compiler should have output an executable which would have simply started and ended the process.

The assembler code:

```
.section .bss
    .lcomm buffer 30000
.section .text
.globl _start
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

Comment: *"even though it should be written to the assembly file"*. Was it? You have `if (strcmp(keyword, "_START") == 0) { fputs("_start:\n", as); ... `

Comment: You might edit your question to include all the strings you create. What is the content of the assembler file you create and what are the command lines you create to run compiler?

Comment: `fscanf(src, "%5s", keyword)` You will never see `_START` in `keyword` as it is too long.

Comment: The first step in debugging would be to look at the `.s` file you're actually assembling.  And if it's not what you thought it would be, single-step this C program that writes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know AT&T syntax (I like NASM), so bear with me.

It seems you're telling the computer to start execution at `_start`, but you're not saying where `_start` is. And so, the linker (`ld`) assumes that it should enter at `00000000040100`. It's simply kind enough to warn you first. Additionally, I'm pretty sure GCC prefers you use `main` instead of `_start` (don't quote me on that).

You'll need your C program to make code that looks more like this:

```
.section .bss
    .lcomm buffer 30000
.section .text
.globl main
main:
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

This compiles on my computer with no warnings nor errors.

Comment: If you link with `gcc foo.o` (without `-nostdlib` or `-nostartfiles`), then yeah the `crt0.o` it links in will already include a `_start` which looks for a `main`.  But the error message from the OP indicates that whatever command they used to link, it didn't include a `_start` symbol at all, since `ld` didn't find one and put the entry point at the top of the text section (which it linked at `0x40100`).  So probably `ld foo.o` or equivalent.  They just need to include a `_start:` label in the asm they're feeding the compiler.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Exactly.

Comment: The code block in your answer wouldn't silence the warning about no `_start` since it doesn't define one.